# how do you add a new view at a specific layout?

Tags: java, android

I want to add an ImageView on a absolute layout thats on a specific place.
the x y coordinates may change dramatically,so I want java code instead of xml code.

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated for a very good reason. I would suggest not using it as it doesn't scale well to all of the hundreds of devices that Android runs on...

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
int width = 100, height = 25, x = 0, y = 200;
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, x, y);
view.setLayoutParams(lp);

absoluteLayout.addView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

so android takes the xml that you work so hard on and then inflates it into View objects which it displays. If you would like to dynamically add your imageview you first need to create it....

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
```

then apply some paramaters and layoutparams if you choose for margins etc. then finall you would take this View and add it to your container view. most people will use

```
 setContentView(R.layout.viewid);
```

to set the layout view. if you have a container in there you can use

```
 RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewcontainerID)
```

then do

```
rl.addView(child) // child is img in this case
```

Let me know if you need more explaining. also look at [LayoutInflator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) if you want to deal with inflating and manipulating xml yourself